# No primary or single unique constructor found for interface org.springframework.ui.Model

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, user-interface, runtime-error

I need some help, if I need to start my project, I am encountering such an Error. What could be the reason?

Console:

```
No primary or single unique constructor found for interface org.springframework.ui.Model
```

Code:

```
package com.Elesgerli.MarketShop_Azer.Controller;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

import com.Elesgerli.MarketShop_Azer.Entity.Cashier;
import com.Elesgerli.MarketShop_Azer.Service.cashierService;
import com.Elesgerli.MarketShop_Azer.Service.productService;

@Controller
public class CashierController{

    @Autowired
    private cashierService cservice;

    @Autowired
    private productService pservice;
    
    @PostMapping("/saveCashier")
    public String save( @RequestBody @ModelAttribute  Model m ,Cashier c) {
        List<Cashier> cashiers=cservice.getAllCashier();
        m.addAttribute("cashier", c);
        cservice.save(c);
        return "redirect:/cashierList";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/delete/{id}")
        public String deleteUser(@PathVariable Integer id) {
         cservice.deletebyId(id);   
         return "redirect:/cashierList";
     }
}
```

I wanted to add a new product by running my project, but it gave such an error.

Answer (score 0):

In "/saveCashier" controller instantiate the Model then create a model attribute with list of all the cashiers as follows :

```
  @PostMapping("/saveCashier")
    public String save(@ModelAttribute  Cashier c, //Object of cashier created as c with details retrieved from the client side
    Model model
    //Model instantiated
    ) {
      cservice.save(c); // cashier saved
      List<Cashier> cashiers=cservice.getAllCashier(); //fetched list of all cahiers
        model.addAttribute("cashiers", cashiers) // List of all cashiers added as attribute
        return "redirect:/cashierList";
        
        
    }
```

If you are unable to understand @ModelAttribute Cashier c then use RequestParam to get data from the client side then instantiate a new cashier object and set it fields using data retrieved using RequestParam. Then save it and add list of all cashiers to a model attribute like below:

```
 @PostMapping("/saveCashier")
    public String save( @RequestParam ("name") String name, //Similary for other properties of cashier like date of birth or anything
    Model model //Model instantiated
    ) {
    Cashier c = new Cashier();
    c.setName(name);
    //Similarly for other fields

     cservice.save(c); // cashier saved
     List<Cashier> cashiers=cservice.getAllCashier(); //fetched list of all cahiers
    
     model.addAttribute("cashiers", cashiers) // List of all cashiers added as attribute

     return "redirect:/cashierList";
        
        
    }
```